# How do i get the IP address of ORACLE 11 g DATABASE on windows 10 to remotely connect to it?

Tags: python, database, oracle, api

I have installed oracle 11g on windows 10 f drive of my laptop. I want know the IP address of the database in order to connect to it using python? How do i find the ip address?

I tried this command:
 select sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;
however it gives me the local host address.

i also tried 
SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_address from dual; 
however this throws an error saying network access denied by access control list

how do i find out the IP address?

Comment: What do you mean by the IP ADDRESS of the database? IP ADDRESS clearly refers to the machine's address on which database is installed. and `select sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;` gives the IP address of the client, not database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no IP Address assigned to the Oracle database. In your case, The database is installed on your own machine so the IP ADDRESS of the database is the same as the IP ADDRESS of your own machine.

```
select sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;
```

The aforementioned query gives the IP ADDRESS of the client which is connected to the database. I think you are misunderstood by this one - It is not the database' IP ADDRESS.

If you need the `HOST_NAME` of the database then you can use the following query. Note that `HOAST_NAME` can be used to connect to the database in the connection string or in **TNS_NAMES.ora**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT INSTANCE_NAME, HOST_NAME FROM V$INSTANCE;
>
> INSTANCE_N HOST_NAME
> ---------- --------------------
> orcl       DESKTOP-0******
>
> SQL>
> ```

I hope it will clear all your doubts.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You must have a `TNSNAMES.ORA` file in your Oracle Configuration. Find that file and open it. There should be ip adresses and needed ports in there.

From official docs:

> By default, tnsnames.ora is located in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
>   directory on UNIX operating systems and in the
>   %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin directory on Windows operating systems.
>   tnsnames.ora can also be stored the following locations:
>
> The directory specified by the TNS_ADMIN environment variable or
>   registry value
>
> On UNIX operating systems, the global configuration directory. For
>   example, on the Solaris Operating System, this directory is
>   /var/opt/oracle.

Then you can connect db with python `cx_Oracle` library using syntax below for connection string.

connection_oracle_textfile.txt -> `username/password@HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME`(you can find all of them but username and password in tnsnames.ora file)

```
import cx_Oracle as cx_Oracle
def get_oracle_table_from_dbm(sql_text):
if 'connection_oracle' not in  globals():
    print('connection does not exist. Try to connect it...')
    f = open('connection_oracle_textfile.txt', "r")
    fx = f.read()         
    ####
    global connection_oracle
    connection_oracle = cx_Oracle.connect(fx)
    ####
    print('connection established!!')

print('Already have connection. Just fetch data!!')
return pd.read_sql(sql_text, con=connection_oracle)
```

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF260)

Comment: i found it however it give me the local host address that is 127.0.0.1

Comment: I edited my answer and add how i connect to oracle db from python. I hope this would be clear. @ashwinisridhar